# Gradle: Can I depend on a module in a different project?

Tags: android-gradle-plugin, android-gradle-2.0

I would like to set up a project with the following structure:

```
Project 1
  + build.gradle
  + settings.gradle
  + module A
      + build.gradle
      + src
      + ...
  + module B
      + build.gradle
      + src
      + ...
Project 2
  + build.gradle
  + settings.gradle
  + module C
      + build.gradle
      + src
      + ...
  + module D
      + build.gradle
      + src
      + ...
```

I would like Project 1's module A to depend on Project 2's module D.  I would like this to be a source (not maven artifact) dependency and to work with gradle 2.14 and Android Studio 2.1.

I do not control the layout of Project 2 or it's root build.gradle.  All I can do is pull it into my workspace and use it.

I have complete control over Project 1, and can set it up any way that I want.  I would prefer that a full build of Project 1 did not cause a complete build of Project 2, just `:project2:moduleD`.  Anything that works, though, will do.

I'd like to know how to set up the build.gradle files for Project 1, and what to put in the `dependency` clause in the build.gradle for Module A.

Answer (score 1):

I'm taking a guess that what you described is not set up a multi-project, that is they are two stand alone projects. If you can't convince the maintainer to publish the artifact anywhere and you always need the latest version of Project 2. Your best bet is to link to the project's output jar file.

`compile files('path/to/Project2/build/output.jar')`

This would require a build to be run on Project 2 after the latest source is pulled onto the system. If you have a specific location of the project you could automate this a bit more but all of it is pretty fragile.

Comment: You are correct that this is not a simple "multi-project" build, in gradle's confusing jargon.  It is instead, as you describe, actually, multiple projects.

Comment: If you are using git you could add it as a submodule in your project and configure the project to be multi-project

Comment: That might work!  How would you configure the respective build files?  The one in Project 2 thinks it is root.  There is a settings.gradle in Project 1.

Comment: Sorry... wrote that too quickly.  It should say that Project 1 thinks it is root and contains a settings.gradle.

Comment: If you control Project 1 couldn't you just update the settings file to include it? Otherwise you can use the GradleRunner or use an execute task to build the project and still have the dependency included how I described in the answer. None of these options are great but are better than nothing.

Comment: It turns out that there really just isn't any way to do what I describe in the question.  There is no way to combine stand-alone projects into a single base project.  Up-voting this answer for multiple reasonable work-arounds.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried a symlink? Make a symlink in project 1 to project D's folder and add it to project 1's settings.gradle

Comment: Yes.  I have tried Symlink and Git Submodule.  The essential problem, that Gradle seems to need a single root directory remains.

Answer (score 0):

you can check blow URl

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_dependencies_between_subprojects.html

and make sure that all this project share same root project

Example for gradle:

rootProject.name = 'sof-portofolio'

include 'core:model1','service:model2'

Comment: As you can see, the question is about two projects, each of which thinks it is the root.  I have tried creating a synthetic root project that contains both but that apparently ignores the sub-project's build.gradle file.